# Create a dynamic list of URLs and titles and save it in an Excel file

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import xlsxwriter

Urllist = []
titlecontentlist =[]
```

I will add different range of index but first need to make this program functional

```
pageno = 123310
# `enter code here`

while pageno<123314:
    Url = "http://pib.nic.in/newsite/PrintRelease.aspx?relid="+ str(pageno) + ""
    page = requests.get(Url)

    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

    titlecontent = tree.xpath('//title/text()')
    heading = tree.xpath('//div[@id="condiv"]/text()')

    #for fj in titlecontent:
    #        maintitle = fj
    #        print type(maintitle)

    #print Url
    #print titlecontent[0]
    #print "\n"*3,Url,"\n"+maintitle
    #for bodycontent in heading: 
     #   b=bodycontent    
      #  print b
    final_list = (['URL' ,'TITLE'],[ Url,titlecontent[0] ])

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('PIB.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    # Some data we want to write to the worksheet.

    i=0
    while i< 3:
        row = i
        col = i

        # Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
        for item, cost in (final_list):
            worksheet.write(row, col,     item)
            worksheet.write(row, col + 1, cost)
            row += 1   
            i+=1   

    #final_list = [ Url,titlecontent[0] ]
    #print final_list

    pageno+=1

workbook.close()
```

I'm stuck at what I should use to save this dynamic expandable list in Excel file.

Comment: brother please help in last line i am unable to think how to insert this dynamic list into an excel file thank you

Comment: Please read [ask] - provide an [mcve] and better problem description than *"unable to"*. SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import xlsxwriter

Urllist = []
titlecontentlist =[]

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('PIB.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write_row(0, 0, ["URL", "TITLE"])
row = 1

for pageno in range(123310, 123314):
    Url = "http://pib.nic.in/newsite/PrintRelease.aspx?relid={}".format(pageno)
    page = requests.get(Url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

    titlecontent = tree.xpath('//title/text()')
    heading = tree.xpath('//div[@id="condiv"]/text()')

    worksheet.write_row(row, 0, [Url, titlecontent[0].strip()])
    row += 1

workbook.close()
```

This would produce an XLSX file looking as follows:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much sir !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! i donot know how to tell you how helpful it was

Comment: You are welcome. Glad it worked. You can click the tick by the answer to accept the solution.

Comment: also can you tell me sources where i can get to learn more about excel handling did not found any good resource on youtube :( :( 
also one quick question if i am increasing the range from 4 to like 50-60 items its taking too much time to process is it normal or i should incorporate some change in codes to reduce time, do you also blog ?

Comment: I just use the online documentation for this library. [xlswriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/)

Comment: The speed is more likely to be an Internet related issue rather than Python or your PC.